# How to consume a chat message, send by user A connected with server instance S1 to a queue/topic, by another user B connected with another instance S2

Tags: microservices, chat, messagebroker

**Problem Context :-**

I want to build a chat system with some queues/topics to handle the chat message when multiple instances of chat service (microservice or monolithic) app are deployed/running.

I understood the entire architecture that how to push a message to broker then consume it with consumer and process it to be delivered as in app message or as push notification if user is not connected.

[image]

**Query :-**

1. **Problem is that I am not able to understand how will I be able to know that my user B is connected to server 2 as highlighted in attached image and invoke server 2's consumer only, not consumers from other instances.**
2. Means even a message is published to queue/topic and I believe by concept it can be consumed by only one thread at a time so How I can make sure that my consumer from the correct instance where user B is connected will be executed.
3. And if user B is not connected to any of the instance I can get that info quickly (like user B is not connected at the moment to any instance)

Hope I am able to explain the problem statement clearly and any help is appreciated.

Comment: It seems like I need to create another service which will store user and instance mapping to some cache system like redis or something but still if you have that information;  Do those instances has to communicate to each other without using message broker? .

Comment: What language are you implementing this in?  There's a reasonable answer in the JVM ecosystem (and a similar one in .Net) that will simplify this quite a bit.  But the basic answer is that you have a stateful application and trying to adapt a stateless architecture to this will be difficult.

Comment: @LeviRamsey I am trying to built it with nodejs stateless architecture but as you said that we need some ecosystem - are you trying to say that I need to use some application server which takes the responsibility of user and node mapping?

Comment: With that constraint, "Stateless + RInK" (e.g. with redis), as the Adya et. al. paper https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RANFtPBPEUKrqOukXnvyGwaLuHTcQHHf/view?usp=sharing describes it, is probably what you'd have to do.

Comment: I would probably map users to shards and then map shards to servers, and have a topic/queue in the message broker for messages to each shard.  You will have to implement something to coordinate this.  The JVM/.Net solutions I was thinking of (Akka/Akka.Net) provide a more efficient way to do this (cluster sharding), but the basic approach is there.

Comment: I also note that the proposed architecture will have to handle the case where a user is believed to be connected to a server at time T when the decision between 5a and 5b is made, and the user is not connected to that server at time T+1 when the server peels off the message.